# Number of neighbors as a function of dimension

Tags: graph-theory, euclidean-geometry, machine-learning

I apologize in advance for perhaps an imprecise formulation of the question.

If I have a point in 1D, it has precisely 2 nearest neighbors independent of choices.

In 2D, if I allow arbitrary orientation then there is an infinite amount of neighbors, but if I discretize on a grid I have either 4 (von Neumann neighborhood) or 8 (Moore neighborhood) or some other choice.

In 3D, arbitrary orientation has a larger infinity (but is it infinitely larger than the 2D case?), and if I discretize on a grid I have 6 (von Neumann neighborhood) or 26 (Moore neighborhood) or some other choice.

In n-dimensions, for example, von Neumann neighborhood goes as 2n, but what are other common choices? What are the typical ways to think about number of neighbors as a function of dimensions in Euclidean space.

If we use a "topology preserving" dimensional reduction (PCA/SOM), then clearly the number of neighbors a point has decreases, what is a good way of thinking of what is preserved?

Thank you!

Comment: you might try the statistics site, they take machine learning questions, people would probably recognize this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-organizing_map   Notice that the tags you used are all incorrect.

Comment: Can you suggest tags? My question is not even about SOM (although I used it as an example), but generally what kind of scaling exists between number of neighbors and number of dimensions and the choice of discretization. 
Edit: I left the graph-theory and euclidean-geometry tags because my question pertains to neighborhood (as in graph theory concept, since it includes a choice of connectidness) and euclidean-geometry (as in how does this work in flat space)

Comment: I will post on stats exchange if I don't get an answer. I really do think that the math exchange is more appropriate, however.